# R refers to non exisiting files during R CMD check

Tags: r, build, package, rstudio, sweave

I want to `R CMD check` with RStudio my package (for this question I call it `pkg`). But I get the following error message:

```
* preparing 'pkg':
* checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... OK
* installing the package to build vignettes
* creating vignettes ...Error in find_vignette_product(name, by = "weave", dir = docdir, engine = engine) : 
  Failed to locate the 'weave' output file (by engine 'utils::Sweave') for vignette with name 'my-vignette'. The following files exist in directory 'C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQLnSjE/Rbuild244434d45c05/pkg/vignettes': 'my-vignette.R', 'my-vignette.Rmd'
Execution halted
Error: Command failed (1)
In addition: Warning message:
`cleanup` is deprecated 
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.
```

One first thing, where something might got wrong is that there is no folder called `RtmpQLnSjE` in my `C:/Users/name/AppData/Local/Temp/` directory. Running my Rmd file by hand, does not generate any errors.

I update RStudio to the latest version 1.1.423 and this is my `SessionInfo()`:

```
R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] MCMCglmm_2.25 ape_5.0       coda_0.19-1   lme4_1.1-15   Rcpp_0.12.15  Matrix_1.2-12 hmi_0.9.4    

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] lattice_0.20-35 corpcor_1.6.9   digest_0.6.15   withr_2.1.1     MASS_7.3-48     grid_3.4.3     
 [7] nlme_3.1-131    cubature_1.3-11 minqa_1.2.4     nloptr_1.0.4    devtools_1.13.4 splines_3.4.3  
[13] tools_3.4.3     yaml_2.1.16     parallel_3.4.3  compiler_3.4.3  memoise_1.1.0   tensorA_0.36
```

Comment: The temp directory is probably unlinked upon the crash. Do you have any code inside the vignette that navigates directories or such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concluding as an answer:

> Failed to locate the 'weave' output file

This error can have several root causes and is not always easy to trace down. However, there is a good chance that it is related to code inside the vignette, in particular code navigating directories and such (e.g. `setwd()` or other functions that may rely on relative paths that could differ between a stand-alone run and the more involved `R CMD check`)

Comment: A supplementary note to the solution of the problem: I sourced some R-files in the vignette. Some of these files moved/were renamed. After changing file-path in the `source()` command, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Now, I have the problem again, even after removing all `source()` commands. Any idea?

Comment: Hard to say- what have you changed otherwise? From what I could see, e.g. bad vignette names could lead to this problem as well

Comment: I have one vignette called `my-vignette.Rmd`

Comment: Ok, that's fine. Probably have to scan through your modifications to see what might raise any suspicions?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran across this when a vignette file had a space in the name (like "My Vignette.Rmd"). It was creating an html file called My-Vignette.html. I think it's the hyphen in the name that was causing issues (based on the answer above along with what I'm seeing.)